# echoprint fingerprint generation Windows vs Linux

Tags: windows, audio-fingerprinting, codegen, echonest, echoprint

I used to generate fingerprint for an audiofile in Windows 7-64bit and on Ubuntu
but fingerprint codes doesnt same (i mean the code field. ). I used compiled Windows source.
does it supposed to be not same or i did something wrong.

**UPDATE**

**Windows**
C:\ecoprint\codegen.exe Kalimba.mp3 > code.txt
**Ubuntu**
/home/regata/echoprint-codegen$ ./echoprint-codegen Kalimba.mp3 > code.txt

the ***samples_decoded*** and ***code_count*** fields are different and ofcourse the code part also.

Answer (score 0):

Generated code remain the same. If you ingested full music file and not opted for start and end time while generating code, it should remain the same. If you ingest that code to any other echoprint server, it will matched by the same music files or part of it, atleast 20 seconds of it mostly.